# In general, what are the theorems that lead us to conclude that a function has a global extremum?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x)=-ax^2+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.

Clearly $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$=$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}f(x)$=$-\infty$.

**What are the theorems that lead us to conclude that this function has a maximum?**

Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}f(x)-\infty$, for any number $N$ there is an $x_0$ such that $|x|>x_0 \implies f(x)<N$.

If we consider the interval $[-x_0,x_0]$, we have a function $f$ that is continuous in this closed interval, and hence $f$ is bounded above and below on this interval. We know that $f$ is bounded above on $[-\infty,-x_0]$ and $[x_0,\infty]$, so $f$ is bounded above.

There is another theorem that tells us that $f$ takes on a maximum value on the closed interval $[-x_0,x_0]$.

If we set $N$ to this maximum value, then for all $x$ not in $[-x_0,x_0]$, we know that $f(x)$ is smaller than the maximum value. Hence we can conclude that the maximum of $f$ on $[-x_0,x_0]$ is the maximum on the entire domain.

Up to this point the theorems use properties of real numbers (excluding least upper bound property) and the concept of continuity.

**I just want to confirm: in general, we don't need notions of derivatives to conclude that a function has a global maximum/minimum? The underlying reasoning to conclude that a function has a global extremum can depend solely on notions of limits, and continuity?**

At this point we don't know yet how to find the maximum. Theorems about derivatives help us here.

In particular, any local max on an open interval (like $f$'s domain) where $f$ is differentiable is a critical point.

In the case of our function, $f$ is differentiable everywhere, so any local maxima occur at critical points. In particular, our global maximum occurs at a critical point.

So at this point we're basically done. $f'(x)=-2ax$ so $0$ is the sole critical point and hence it must be the global maximum. This latter conclusion is either the result of the previous reasoning, or we can reason as follows: $f'(x)>0$ for $x<0$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $x>0$, hence $f$ is increasing up to $0$ and decreasing after $0$. $0$ is thus a global maximum.

I am trying to figure out in general what theory I rely on every time I find maxima/minima of well-behaved functions like my example. It seems that the actual reasoning can be based solely on the notion of continuity or it can use notions of derivatives.

It seems that to a degree we use "interpretation" or "heuristics" to conclude that one of them is a global extremum, because no one theorem is one-size-fits-all situations (we also had to put together an interpretation to reach our conclusion when we relied simply on continuity as well).

Contrast this with finding local extrema: we know that all we need to do is find critical points and consider points where $f$ isn't differentiable.

Am I right to conclude that finding global extrema is always a case of interpreting a particular situation (according to various theorems), rather than applying one theorem?

Comment: Sorry, not clear on what your question is. Neither local nor global extrema are necessarily tied to continuity or limits or differentiability.

Comment: So what are they tied to after all? I can reach a conclusion about the existence of global maxima and minima by reasoning as I did above (either simply considering continuity for example, or by reasoning using derivatives. It seems that my reasoning depends on the situation at hand, and each function is different. Is there a clear cut recipe to conclude that a function has global extrema? If so, what is the recipe, ie, what are the theorems that have to be applied an in what order?

Comment: They are tied to the function, but not all functions are differentiable, or even continuous. There is no general "recipe" that works in all cases.